# AES Encryption done in OpenSSL is decrypted successfully but fails when encrypted in Java

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes

I have used the below OpenSSL code to do an AES encryption which is decrypting successfully in the Tax website

```
openssl rand 48 > 48byterandomvalue.bin
hexdump /bare 48byterandomvalue.bin > 48byterandomvalue.txt

set /a counter=0
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%i in (48byterandomvalue.txt) do (
set /a counter=!counter!+1
set var=%%i
if "!counter!"=="1" (set aes1=%%i)
if "!counter!"=="2" (set aes2=%%i)
if "!counter!"=="3" (set iv=%%i)
)

set result1=%aes1:~0,50%
set result1=%result1: =%
set result2=%aes2:~0,50%
set result2=%result2: =%
set aeskey=%result1%%result2%
set initvector=%iv:~0,50%
set initvector=%initvector: =%

openssl aes-256-cbc -e -in PAYLOAD.zip -out PAYLOAD -K %aeskey% -iv %initvector%

openssl rsautl -encrypt -certin -inkey test_public.cer -in 
48byterandomvalue.bin -out 000000.00000.TA.840_Key
```

But I wanted to do the same this in Java as part of migration, so i used the **javax.crypto** and **java.security** libraries but the decryption is failing when I upload the file on the Tax website

```
//creating the random AES-256 secret key
SecureRandom srandom = new SecureRandom(); 
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(256);
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();
byte[] aesKeyb = secretKey.getEncoded();

//creating the initialization vector
byte[] iv = new byte[128/8];
srandom.nextBytes(iv);
IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
str = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);

//fetching the Public Key from certificate
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test_public.cer");
CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(fin);
PublicKey pk = certificate.getPublicKey();

//encrypting the AES Key with Public Key
Cipher RSACipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
RSACipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pk);
byte[] RSAEncrypted = RSACipher.doFinal(aesKeyb);

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("000000.00000.TA.840_Key");
out.write(RSAEncrypted);
out.write(iv);
out.close();
```

Also, the AES key generated in java is different from the one generated via openssl. Can you guys please help.

**EDIT 1:**
Below is the code for AES Encrpytion used:

```
Cipher AESCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
AESCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, ivspec);
byte[] AESEncrypted = AESCipher.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
String encryptedStr = new String(AESEncrypted);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, I have only mentioned the encryption of AES Key with RSA in java which is equivalent to "openssl rsautl -encrypt -certin -inkey test_public.cer -in 
48byterandomvalue.bin -out 000000.00000.TA.840_Key"
And I have not mentioned the AES 256 CBC encryption java code here as the key itself is not matching. So I didn't wanted to post the further code here. Anyways now I have updated that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The data that script and Java-code encrypt with RSA differ:

  The script generates a random 48-bytes-sequence and stores it in the file `48byterandomvalue.bin`. The first 32 bytes are used as AES key, the last 16 bytes as IV. Key and IV are used to encrypt the file `PAYLOAD.zip` with AES-256 in CBC-mode and store it as file `PAYLOAD`.  The file `48byterandomvalue.bin` is encrypted with RSA and stored as file `000000.00000.TA.840_Key`.

  In the Java-code, a random 32-bytes AES key and a random 16-bytes IV are generated. Both are used to perform the encryption with AES-256 in CBC-mode. The AES key is encrypted with RSA, concatenated with the unencrypted IV and the result is stored in the file `000000.00000.TA.840_Key`.

  The content of the file `000000.00000.TA.840_Key` is different for script and Java-code. For the Java-code to generate the `file 000000.00000.TA.840_Key` with the script-logic, the *unencrypted* AES key must be concatenated with the unencrypted IV and *this* result must be encrypted with RSA:

  ```
  ...
  //byte[] aesKeyb byte-array with random 32-bytes key
  //byte[] iv      byte-array with random 16-bytes iv
  byte[] key_iv = new byte[aesKeyb.length + iv.length];
  System.arraycopy(aesKeyb, 0, key_iv, 0, aesKeyb.length);
  System.arraycopy(iv, 0, key_iv, aesKeyb.length, iv.length);
  ...
  byte[] RSAEncrypted = RSACipher.doFinal(key_iv);
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("000000.00000.TA.840_Key");
  out.write(RSAEncrypted);
  out.close();
  ...
  ```

  Note: The IV doesn't have to be secret and therefore doesn't need to be encrypted. The encryption is only necessary to generate the result of the script in the Java-code.
- Another problem concerns the conversion of arbitrary binary data into strings. This generally leads to corrupted data if the encoding is unsuitable (e.g. ASCII or UTF8). Therefore

  ```
  ...
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
  str = new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);           // Doesn't work: ASCII (7-bit) unsuitable for arbitrary bytes, *        
  ...
  byte[] AESEncrypted = AESCipher.doFinal(str.getBytes("UTF-8")); // Doesn't work: UTF-8 unsuitable for arbitrary bytes and additionally different from * 
  String encryptedStr = new String(AESEncrypted);                 // Doesn't work: UTF-8 unsuitable for arbitrary bytes
  ...
  ```

  should be replaced by

  ```
  ...
  byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath));
  ...
  byte[] AESEncrypted = AESCipher.doFinal(encoded);
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("PAYLOAD");
  out.write(AESEncrypted);
  out.close();
  ...
  ```

  A suitable encoding to store arbitrary data in a string is e.g. Base64, but this isn't necessary in this case, because Base64-encoding isn't used in the script either.
- Try these changes. If other issues occur, it would be best to test AES encryption, RSA encryption, and `key_iv`-generation *separately*. This makes it easier to isolate bugs.

Comment: That's well explained. Let me try and see. Also, I have a doubt on the settings used to Encrypt. "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" and just "RSA". What's the difference ?

Comment: `RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` means RSA with PKCS1 v1.5 padding. The latter is a padding scheme which is described in detail in [RFC 8017, section 7.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#section-7.2). ECB has no meaning in the context of RSA, is a rather inappropriate term (see also [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/26539)) and can be ignored. [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-rsautl.html) uses PKCS1 v1.5 padding by default, so the RSA encryption is identical in the script and the Java-code.